# Utilizar position absolute para deixar elemento sempre no bottom mas sem sobrepor outro elemento

Tags: html, css, scss

Atualmente eu tenho uma sidenav feita com [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview).

Eu tenho uma listagem com menu e submenus, e no final tenho um logo.
Meu problema é que quando todos os menus dentro do meu sidenav são abertos, eles acabam colidindo com o meu logo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
*(Removi a visibilidade dos itens do menu e o logo)*

A colisão acontece no menu "Logs" e o logo.

Tentei das seguintes formas:

**HTML:**

```
<img id="logo" src="../../../assets/logo">

#logo{
    width: 120px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

Atualmente funciona bem se os menus estão fechados, meu logo é posicionado no bottom do meu sidenav, porém se o usuário for abrindo os menus colide com o menu "Logs".

Eu tentei também:

```
#logo{
    width: 120px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    right: 0;
    /* position: absolute; */
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

Dessa forma o menu não colide com o logo, mas o meu logo não fica centralizado no final do meu sidenav.

Tem alguma forma do meu logo ficar centralizado no final do meu sidenav sem que haja possibilidade dele colidir com os menus abertos?

**HTML Completo:**

```
<mat-sidenav-container hasBackdrop="false" class="container-sidenav">
    <mat-sidenav [(opened)]="opened" #sidenav mode="over">
        <mat-list>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <div id="avatarDash" class=" pointerCursor">
                            <svg id="svgDash" class="svgIconeMenu" style="width:40px;height:40px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                <path fill="rgb(161,196,66)" d="1,3H3V13H11V3M21,11H13V21H21V11M11,15H3V21H11V15Z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-9">
                        <div class="col-12 pointerCursor">
                            <span class="tipografiaDescricaoIcone">Menu 1</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="menuCadastros">
                    <div (click)="changeMenuCadastros()" class="row">
                        <div class="col-3 colAtiva">
                            <div class="pointerCursor">
                                <svg class="svgIconeMenu"
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="37px" height="37px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
                                    <path d="M20.9 2-2V8c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm0 12H4V8h16v10z"/>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <span class="tipografiaDescricaoIcone">Cadastros</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3 pointerCursor">
                            <i class="fa fa-caret-down lightgray" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="alinhaSideNav">
                            <span (click)="verificaPermissao(1,'operadores')" class="tipografianivel2 hover-effect">Operadores</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="alinhaSideNav">
                            <span (click)="verificaPermissao(11,'transportadora')" class="tipografianivel2 hover-effect">Transportadoras</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        <img id="logo" src="../../../assets/logo.png">

    </mat-sidenav>  

<mat-sidenav-content>
```

Comment: Cara vc tem que colocar o HTML ai tb. e se possível o código inteiro do menu para que a gente possa simular o seu problema.... Só com o que vc postou ai não da para simular seu problema e te dar uma resposta concreta. Mas na versão que está com flex tente colocar justify-self: center; ou justify-content: center; para ver se resolve

Comment: @hugocsl adicionei o html

Comment: ja tentou com position fixed?

Comment: sim, com position fixed o menu continua colidindo com o logo quando aberto

Answer (score 0):

Fica difícil entender o que você quer dizer com "colidir" e analisar seu código apenas com o HTML (sem CSS e com tags do Angular Material). Futuramente, insira seu código na pergunta (**ctrl+M** ou ícone de "**trecho de código**" acima do editor). Lá você pode colocar o HTML renderizado pelo navegador e folhas de estilo do Angular Material encontradas online.

Imaginando que "colidir" significa que o logotipo aparece por cima do menu de logs, isso acontece pois o logotipo tem **`position:absolute`** mas você pode contornar isso aplicando **`position:relative`** (ou **`position:absolute`**) em um elemento que contenha todos os itens do menu (no seu caso há uma **`div.container`** que aliás não está fechando com  após os itens) e em seguida aplicando **`z-index`** maior que do logotipo.

Execute o código a seguir para ver o exemplo.

```css
/* CSS IMPORTANTE - que pode solucionar seu problema */
nav .container { position:relative; z-index:2; }
.logo { position:absolute; top:150px; left:0; right:0; margin:auto; width:50px; background:red; }

/* CSS apenas para visualização */
body { padding-left:50px; }
nav { background:#0000dd; color:#fff; position:fixed; left:-110px; top:0; height:100%; width:150px; }
nav:hover { left:0; }
nav a { display:block; margin:5px; padding:5px; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; }
nav a p { display:none; }
nav a:hover { background:#0000FF; }
nav a:hover p { display:block; }
nav span { float:right; }
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class='container'>
    <a href='#'>Home<span></span></a>
    <a href='#'>Pastas<span></span></a>
    <a href='#'>Mensagens<span>✉</span>
      <p>submenu</p>
      <p>submenu</p>
      <p>submenu</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class='logo'>LOGO</div>
</nav>
<main>
<h1>SITE</h1>
Posicione o mouse no menu ao lado, depois vá em mensagens e note que o submenu passa por cima do logotipo. Mesmo que o logotipo use position absolute para se posicionar, pois agora seu z-index é mais baixo que da container do menu.<br><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque pretium dapibus rutrum. Morbi tincidunt ultrices justo porttitor commodo. In quis enim at augue cursus posuere. Nam luctus dolor nisi, non varius justo pellentesque ut. Morbi ac ex libero. Sed sapien justo, rutrum in nulla in, luctus viverra justo. Praesent nec purus ut lorem sollicitudin convallis. Vivamus ut faucibus lectus, at pharetra arcu.

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus dapibus vulputate massa, sed cursus arcu tincidunt sit amet. Morbi rutrum consectetur velit sed sagittis. Cras iaculis eget neque eget dapibus. Donec vulputate leo mollis nulla vehicula, id bibendum leo hendrerit. Morbi id odio ac orci pharetra cursus nec in dui. Vivamus sed neque orci.

Suspendisse vitae vestibulum nibh. Quisque nec aliquet tellus, at porta justo. Phasellus vestibulum, risus sed facilisis lacinia, nibh eros varius justo, sit amet ultrices lorem est quis lectus. Nam laoreet mollis velit nec aliquet. Phasellus sem dolor, faucibus a leo sodales, cursus viverra quam. Nunc ut mi ut nulla elementum dignissim ac quis neque. Pellentesque ultrices lacus quis arcu rutrum condimentum. Mauris imperdiet scelerisque pellentesque. Nunc gravida nibh sed enim vestibulum, in aliquam nisi scelerisque. Sed at sapien sem. Praesent tincidunt auctor elit ac condimentum. Donec ultrices odio suscipit orci hendrerit efficitur.
</main>
```